# Rails Nested Resource not creating from Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, nested-routes

I am trying to create a simple data puller from the yahoo finance gem. I have a nested route setup for Security that has_many Price

The Price controller is as follows:

```
class PricesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_security
  before_action :set_price, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @price = Price.new
  end

  private
  def set_price
    @price = Price.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end

  def price_params
    params.require(:price).permit(:date, :open, :high, :low, :close, :volume, :security_id)
  end

  def set_security
    @security = Security.find_by_ticker(params[:security_id])
  end
end
```

The nested route works fine to manually create the child Price record from a form. I'm trying to create a Price record for each result in the array that gets generated from the following code:

```
class Datapuller

  def self.download_historical
    yahoo_client = YahooFinance::Client.new
    data = yahoo_client.historical_quotes("FB")

    data.each do |i|
      @ticker = Security.find_by_ticker(data[0].symbol )
      price = @ticker.prices.new()
      price.security_id = @ticker
      price.date = data[0].date
      price.open = data[0].open
      price.high = data[0].high
      price.low = data[0].low
      price.close = data[0].close
     end
   end
 end
```

I'd like to call this method from a button link but for now I have the following code on the Security View:

```
<%= Datapuller.download_historical %>
```

This also give me the benefit to see the data that is getting loaded from the array.

With the above code I can create a child Price to a parent Security using a form and I can make the call from the yahoo finance gem. However, the array is not creating a Price record for each line in the array.

What am I missing in this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why you aren't getting anything saved in your array of `@ticker.prices` is because you're instantiating them via `price = @ticker.prices.new()` but you're never saving them. You need to call the following after you set all the attributes:

```
price.save
```

to get that record

1. saved via Active Record and
2. associated with your `@ticker`.

If you skim through the [Active Record basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) it will help a ton to understand the life cycle of a record (save, validate, delete, etc).

You also will probably want to look at making your views and routes more [resourceful](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), which is the Rails default. If you use a `resource :prices` in your routes, Rails will use it's convention to help you along the way.

So for instance, you'd have a `create` method on your controller that would solely be in charge of calling your `Datapuller.download_historical` - and that way you can make a button that links to that route just by saying `<%= link_to 'Create Price', prices_path, method: :create %>` that would create your prices on click. There are more ways to further let Rails help you write less code but that's a start. If you want more reading, I think M. Hartl does a great job of explaining [RESTful resources](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#table-RESTful_users) in his intro guide.